# Linear regression and variability from this line

Tags: python, linear-regression, curve-fitting

I have a set of data, and am using a linear regression line to measure the "best fit" line for the whole sample set.

What is the statistical function called that measures the amount of variability from this line?

For the examples below, I'd prefer lower amplitudes and volatility (the red line on the below - second image preferred to the first):

[image: This is A]

[image: This is B]

Comment: Do you refer to the Loss Function?  RSS (Residual Sum of Squares), MSE (Mean Square Error), ...?

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear, statistics is new to me. It's the amount of variation of the data samples from the mean line - for example, the maximum and minimum variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I clearly understood your question, you are looking for a Coefficient of determination. It is the proportion of the variation in the dependent variable that is predictable from the independent variable(s).